# Initializing fails with DbContext inheritance

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance, dbcontext

I am faced with a completely incomprehensible problem.
I have this code and it works every time I use it.

```cs
public class FirstContext : DbContext
{
    private FirstContext()) { }

    public FirstContext(string ConnectionString, int ID) : base(ConnectionString)
    {
        _ID = ID;
        Database.SetInitializer(new FirstInitializer<FirstContext>());
        Database.Initialize(true);   // probably unnecessary
    }

    private int _ID;

    public DbSet<UserModel> Users { get; set; }
}


public class FirstInitializer<TContext> : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<FirstContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(FirstContext context)
    {
        UserModel user;

        user = new UserModel() { Password = "EDCBA", Username = "User1", Email = "temp@temp.com" };
        context.Users.Add(user);

        user = new UserModel() { Password = "ABCDE", Username = "User2", Email = "temp@temp.com" };
        context.Users.Add(user);

        context.SaveChanges();
        base.Seed(context);
    }
}

FirstContext db = new FirstContext(connectionString, 1);
db.Users.Find("User1");
```

As soon the last line is executed the table will be created and filled with the two users.

To avoid creating the instance with the connection string and the id I wanted to do this:

```cs
public class SecondContext : FirstContext
{
    public SecondContext() : base("Data Source=........", 1) // a valid connection string
    {
    }
}

SecondContext db = new SecondContext();
db.Users.Find("User1");
```

**Problem:**
When *db.Users.Find("User1");* is executed, it creates the table but does not fill it with the two users.
Even when I try this it results in the same problem:

```cs
public class SecondContext : FirstContext
{
    public SecondContext() : base("Data Source=........", 1) // a valid connection string
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new FirstInitializer<FirstContext>());
    }
}

SecondContext db = new SecondContext();
db.Database.Initialize(true);
db.Users.Find("User1");
```

Can anybody tell me where my mistake is, please?

Comment: @ MikeGuthrie Because of the inheritance of generic _DropCreateDatabaseAlways<FirstContext>_ I have to specify the TContext as FirstContext

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to accomplish with inheritance, but you can mark the FirstContext (base) as abstract or you could set it's initializer to null.

Comment: @MikeGuthrie I have tried your code, but unfortunately it gives the same result: an empty table :-(

Comment: Is _all_ you're after just a way to create the context with some default connection string and ID?  But don't want to update the parameterless `FirstContext()` constructor to provide them?

Comment: @MikeGuthrie Yes ... and I would like to know why my code does not work. ;-) The problem is, that I have a bundle of connection strings and ID's which belongs together. Of couse I _could_ always use something like `FirstContext(Settings.ConnectionString, Settings.ID)`, but that means a lot my _confusing_ code and a lot more writing. So I _tried_ to make it more save, easier and better.

Comment: @Ronin Wish I could help on _why_ it doesn't work.  But, I can offer, it looks like you're using inheritance for something that could just be accomplished with static (or extension, if you preferred) methods.